# Selenium WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to scrape a Javascript page with Python. Seeing that PhantomJS is already deprecated, I am trying to use headless Chrome webdriver to load the page to no avail.

The driver is loaded but the code mostly crashes either during the wait or upon retrieval of the page source.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def fetch(search):
    BASE_URL = 'https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query='
    DELAY = 10
    html = None

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

    search_url = BASE_URL + search
    driver.get(search_url)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'content')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Took too long to load.')
    else:
        html = driver.page_source
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return html
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch.py", line 44, in <module>
    test = fetch(s)
  File "fetch.py", line 31, in fetch
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'content')))
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 64, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 415, in _find_element
    raise e
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/jrmanrique/.virtualenvs/nltk-kor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=81.0.4044.122)
```

System Info:

```
Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows
Google Chrome 81.0.4044.122
Chromedriver 81.0.4044.69
Selenium 3.141.0
```

Comment: Can you run the following and then try running your code?
`wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -`



`sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> 

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'`
`apt-get -y update`
`apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable`
`ln -s /usr/bin/chromium-browser && chmod 777 /usr/bin/chromium-browser`

Also make sure you put `chromedriver` inside `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Consider the white space as end of command